# CommandType.Text vs CommandType.StoredProcedure

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net

Is there any benefit to explicitly using the StoredProcedure CommandType as opposed to just using a Text Command?  In other words, is

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC StoredProc(@p1, @p2)");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", 1);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", 2);
```

any worse than

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProc");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", 1);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", 2);
```

EDIT: Fixed bad copy paste job (again).  Also, the whole point of the question is for a data access class.  I'd much rather be able to pass the stored proc name and parameters in one line as opposed to extra lines for each parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One difference is how message pumping happens.

Where I used to work we had a number of batch processes that ran over night. Many of them simply involved running a stored procedure. We used to schedule these using sql server jobs, but moved away from it to instead call the procedures from a .Net program. This allowed us to keep *all* our scheduled tasks in one place, even the ones that had nothing to do with Sql Server.

It also allowed us to build better logging functionality into the .Net program that calls the procedures, so that the logging from all of the overnight processes was consistent. The stored procedures would use the sql `print` and `raiserror` functions, and the .Net program will receive and log those. What we learned was that `CommandType.StoredProcedure` would *always* buffer these messages into batches of about 50. The .Net code wouldn't see any log events until the procedure finished or flushed the buffer, no matter what options you set on the connection or what you did in your sql. `CommandType.Text` fixed this for us.

As a side issue, I'd use explicit types with your query parameters.  Letting .Net try to infer your parameter types can cause issues in some situations.

Comment: Any examples on the implicit typing issue? I've heard that one a few times, but never seen it.

Comment: Say you have an index on a varchar column.  .Net will assume nvarchar and not be able to use the index.

Comment: Following that...so if I have a stored proc with a varchar argument, and I pass a string in, what happens?

Comment: It's less of an impact for SPs than for adhoc queries. SQL Server will just do an extra conversion from nvarchar to varchar once, rather than scrap a whole index. But it's still bad. Take datetime: if .Net gets a datetime column wrong and sql server can't implicitly convert, you've got a problem.

Comment: [continued] I haven't personally seen that last example because I always use explicit types on my query parameters, but I know it's possible.

Comment: I could see that if you don't use an explicit date time type.  I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: You can use the WITH NOWAIT hint when using raiserror to avoid the message buffering.

Comment: @Mark old now, but I do recall testing NOWAIT at the time, and that CommandType.StoredProcedure still buffered. But that was more than 4 years ago. A more recent .Net release may have fixed this.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Oh, you might actually be correct about that. I remember making this work somehow with stored procedures. WITH NOWAIT was part of that solution, I think I also had to set SqlConnection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

It's cleaner.

You're calling a stored procedure, why not just use the `CommandType.StoredProcedure`?

Comment: Because I'm writing a DB layer that allows using a parameter array for arguments.

Comment: +1 - CLARITY is the magic word for any long-term project which needs to be concertned with things like maintainability! :)