# Running SP using exec in ado.net

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CommandType.Text vs CommandType.StoredProcedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643880/commandtype-text-vs-commandtype-storedprocedure)

I have been working on a already developed project in .Net and I came through that commandText for running a SP is like 'exec SPname' so that the commandType of SqlCommand remains text instead of Stored Procedure.Rest code is similar as used in ado.net. Is its performance is better as compared to traditional one?