# Using SQL queries in C#. Trouble with defining stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm sharing a snippet from my code below:

```
string str = "select * from contacts";
DataSet dt = Global.getdatatablefromquery(str);
ExcelGrid.DataSource = dt;
ExcelGrid.DataBind();
```

I am changing all my queries to stored procedures, but I don't know exactly how will I define my stored procedure in this code? I want something like:

```
string str = "storedprocedurename";
DataSet dt = Global.getdatatablefromquery(str);
ExcelGrid.DataSource = dt;
ExcelGrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: Have you ever used ADO.NET in your `Global.getdatatablefromquery` method? If so, just change your `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 choices *(as far as I know)*:

**1.** Execute it as `Text` by specifying EXEC `explicitly`.

*Eg:*

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC storedprocedurename(@p1, @p2)");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", 1);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", 2);
```

**2.** You can use `CommandType` as `StoredProcedure`

*Eg:*

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("storedprocedurename");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", 1);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", 2);
```

> The difference between the 2 approaches is how message pumping happens.([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/643964/1155650))

Using the second approach in which the `CommandType` is explicitly specified as `StoredProcedure` is more clear and cleaner.